# Pytest can't find module (Tree structure different)

Tags: python, pytest

So I'm trying to use `pytest` to test several python modules that reside in another different folder. Is there some way this can be done (without changing the code file `spmatrix.py` or `position.py`)?

I'm trying to test, for example, the module `spmatrix.py` using the test `test_spmatrix_priv.py`.

Result:

```
pytest .
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.3, pytest-7.1.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /mnt/c/Users/Dell/Desktop/FCT/DTSD/P/labs-dtsd
collecting 36 items / 1 error                                           collected 36 items / 2 errors

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________ ERROR collecting tests/spmatrix_procedural/test_spmatrix.py __________
ImportError while importing test module '/mnt/c/Users/Dell/Desktop/FCT/DTSD/P/labs-dtsd/tests/spmatrix_procedural/test_spmatrix.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/spmatrix_procedural/test_spmatrix.py:2: in <module>
    from spmatrix_procedural.spmatrix import *
spmatrix_procedural/spmatrix.py:1: in <module>
    from position import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'position'
_______ ERROR collecting tests/spmatrix_procedural/test_spmatrix_priv.py _______
ImportError while importing test module '/mnt/c/Users/Dell/Desktop/FCT/DTSD/P/labs-dtsd/tests/spmatrix_procedural/test_spmatrix_priv.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/spmatrix_procedural/test_spmatrix_priv.py:4: in <module>
    from spmatrix_procedural.spmatrix import *
spmatrix_procedural/spmatrix.py:1: in <module>
    from position import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'position'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR tests/spmatrix_procedural/test_spmatrix.py
ERROR tests/spmatrix_procedural/test_spmatrix_priv.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 2 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================== 2 errors in 0.69s ===============================
```

Project tree

```
.
├── DTSD-Lab03_v1_0.pdf
├── DTSD-Lab03_v1_2.pdf
├── IOTsensors
│   ├── Provider.py
│   ├── ProviderSensorTemperature.py
│   ├── ProviderSensorTemperatureDHT22.py
│   ├── ProviderSensorTemperatureMPU6050.py
│   ├── ProviderSensorTemperatureNTC.py
│   ├── links.txt
│   └── main.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
│   ├── conftest.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
│   ├── position.cpython-310.pyc
│   ├── spmatrix.cpython-310.pyc
│   ├── test_position.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
│   ├── test_position_priv.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
│   ├── test_spmatrix.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
│   └── test_spmatrix_priv.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
├── fibonacci
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
│   │   ├── fibonacci.cpython-310.pyc
│   │   ├── fibonacci.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── test_fibonacci.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
│   │   └── test_fibonacci.cpython-38-pytest-7.0.1.pyc
│   ├── fibonacci.py
│   └── tests
├── html
│   ├── position.html
│   └── spmatrix.html
├── poolgate
├── specification
│   ├── pool_gate.kra
│   └── pool_gate.kra~
├── spmatrix_procedural
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
│   │   ├── position.cpython-310.pyc
│   │   └── spmatrix.cpython-310.pyc
│   ├── position.pdf
│   ├── position.py
│   ├── spmatrix.pdf
│   └── spmatrix.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    ├── fibonacci
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   └── test_fibonacci.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
    │   └── test_fibonacci.py
    └── spmatrix_procedural
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
        │   ├── test_position.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
        │   ├── test_position_priv.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
        │   ├── test_spmatrix.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
        │   └── test_spmatrix_priv.cpython-310-pytest-7.1.1.pyc
        ├── position_different.py
        ├── pytest_adt_spmatrix_priv.txt
        ├── pytest_position_priv.py
        ├── pytest_position_priv.txt
        ├── pytest_position_pub.py
        ├── pytest_position_pub.txt
        ├── pytest_spmatrix_priv.py
        ├── pytest_spmatrix_priv.txt
        ├── pytest_spmatrix_pub.py
        ├── pytest_spmatrix_pub.txt
        ├── test_lizard.txt
        ├── test_position.py
        ├── test_position_priv.py
        ├── test_spmatrix.py
        └── test_spmatrix_priv.py
```

`spmatrix.py` (imports):

```
from position import *
from typing import Union


(...)
```

`test_spmatrix_priv.py` (imports):

```
import pytest
import sys, os

from spmatrix_procedural.spmatrix import *
(...)
```

Also the VScode testing extension can't find the tests:
[image: Testing extension in VScode]